# Scraping Table Data from Multiple URLS, but first link is repeating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, python-requests

I'm looking to iterate through the URL with "count" as variables between 1 and 65.

Right now, I'm close but really struggling to figure out the last piece.  I'm receiving the same table (from variable 1) 65 times, instead of receiving the different tables.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc/{count}'

res = []

for count in range(1, 65):
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    df = df_list[-1]
    res.append(df)

    print(res)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: you are setting the value of `url` only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few errors:

- Your URL was templated incorrectly. It remains at `.../{count}` literally, without substituting or updating from the loop variable.
- If you want to get page 1 to 65, use `range(1, 66)`
- Unless you want to export only the last dataframe, you need to concatenate all of them first

```py
# No count here, we will add it later
url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc'
res = []

for count in range(1, 66):
    # pd.read_html accepts a URL too so no need to make a separate request
    df_list = pd.read_html(f"{url}/{count}")
    res.append(df_list[-1])

pd.concat(res).to_csv('my data.csv')
```

Comment: This is amazing - UGH I'm learning quickly but boy does it suck. Thanks for such a thorough explanation - really is super helpful.

Comment: if you don't mind, what does the "f" do in read_html? I'm doing some googling but not seeing anything super clear for that specific piece

Comment: It's called f-string. It's a better way to interpolate variables into a string: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/